# how to deserialize an anonymus object in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

i'm putting some serialize data into value of items in CheckBoxList

```
chkList.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.title, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ME_ID = item.id, ME_Start = Convert.ToDateTime(item.start), ME_End = Convert.ToDateTime(item.end) })));
```

now after user select the items i need to read the the value back to the object

```
List<string> selectedValues = chkList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .Where(li => li.Selected)
            .Select(li => li.Value)
            .ToList();

        foreach (string item in selectedValues) { 
            //what to write here?
        }
```

how can i read the string into object? maybe i need create a strongly type?

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType`?

Comment: Yes and It's work. i Didnt Know this Method.